# How to setup YoutubePlayer in a way to make it continue playing the video even when i have a container wrapped in a gestureDetector in a Stack?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, youtube-player-flutter

Hi I am working on a Flutter Project where I have a Stack widget having youtubePlayer widget which is wrapped in an absorb pointer to avoid getting interactions from the container wrapped in a gesture detector which is enabled when islock is true. this gesturedetector is in the same stack in which I have this youtubeplayer. so, when I tab on the container/gesture detector my youtubePlayer get paused and as far as I know it get paused due to its builtin nature that currently its not active or something it get paused. Is there any way that i can stop my video from getting paused?
here is the sample code I am using:

```dart
body: Stack(
        children: [
          IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: _isLock,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                                  
                    child: YoutubePlayer(
                      controller: _controller,
                      showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                      onReady: () {
                        _isPlayerReady = true;
                        playVideo(_currentIndex);
                      },
                    ),
                  
                ),
                if (!_isFullScreen)
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: widget.videos.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final video = widget.videos[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: Container(
                            width: 90.0, 
                            child: Image.network(video.thumbnailUrl,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                          title: Text(video.title),
                          subtitle: Text(video.duration),
                          onTap: () => playVideo(index),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (_isLock)
            Positioned.fill(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  

                   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Hi There!'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child:Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      
                      child: Center(
                        child: Transform.translate(
                          offset: _offset,
                          child: _showImage,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```